# Android Rigntone play method froze activity if started in main thread

Tags: android

Android Rigntone play method froze activity if started in main thread.

Have anybody faced same problem? How you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Ringtone class, Media Player should be used. It allows to preload melody in background.